# change Width Gridview While containing 100 words;

Tags: c#, asp.net

change Width Gridview While  containing 100 words;

```
gridInbox.Rows[i].Cells[4].Wrap = false;
gridInbox.Rows[i].Cells[4].Width  = 10;
```

does not work;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you add more details as to exactly what you are doing and what the desired outcome is?

Assuming you are trying to make the cells not get any bigger regardless of the amount of text?  If so you can enforce a style of the produced tables by setting the css:

```
gridviewStyle
{
    table-layout:fixed;
}

gridviewColumnStyle
{
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    width: 10;
}
```

Set your `GridView` and the columns you want to enforce to use the above css.